# Как построить общение между несколькими потоками с помощью Exchanger Java

Tags: java, многопоточность, exchange

Всем здравствуйте! Я новичок в Java. В данный момент изучаю тему многопоточности и у меня возникла проблема, решение которой или хоть бы какую-то подсказку к ней не могу найти нигде.
 Есть задача: *Четверо бардов пришли в таверну. У каждого из них есть своя песня. В середине вечера, хозяин
заведения попросил их исполнить песню. Прилично выпив, барды не смогли прийти к
согласию кто именно будет петь и решили составить общую песню на основе остальных. Было
решено, что хозяин этого захудалого местечка, получит максимум 8 слов. Барды придумали
способ, как составить текст, да так, чтобы каждый поучаствовал. А именно:
Один из четверых называет слово, остальные его запоминают. Потом так делает следующий. И
так восемь раз, по два раза каждый соответственно, но не два раза подряд. В конце, барды
хором поют песню, вызывая бурные овации посетителей зала и недовольство хозяина таверны
столь кратким произведением.
Для решения этой задачи нужно воспользоваться классом Exchanger(иначе как барды будут друг
другу что-то говорить?) и классом Phaser (иначе как барды поймут, когда нужно делиться
словом?)*
Программа не заканчивается, не могу понять как решить эту проблему. Ещё интересно узнать адекватную критику и рекомендации по поводу кода. Спасибо

```java
package MultiThreading.ExchangerPhaser;

import java.util.concurrent.Exchanger;
import java.util.concurrent.Phaser;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Bard extends Thread {

    private volatile static boolean isSong = false;
    private  static AtomicInteger countsWords = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private String name;
    private String song;
    private String newSong = "";
    private Exchanger<String> exchanger;
    private Phaser phaser;
    private Semaphore semaphore;

    public Bard(String name, String song, Exchanger<String> exchanger, Phaser phaser, Semaphore semaphore) {
        this.name = name;
        this.song = song;
        this.exchanger = exchanger;
        this.phaser = phaser;
        this.semaphore = semaphore;
        this.start();
    }

    private synchronized boolean isSong(){
        return !isSong && (isSong = true);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String[] songArr = song.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            try {
                semaphore.acquire();
                    String word = songArr[(int) (Math.random() * songArr.length)] + " ";
                    if (isSong()) {
                        newSong += word;
                        countsWords.getAndIncrement();
                        exchanger.exchange(newSong);

                    } else {
                        newSong = exchanger.exchange("");
                        newSong += word;
                        countsWords.getAndIncrement();
                        System.out.println(name + ": " + newSong);
                        if (countsWords.get() < 8) {
                            exchanger.exchange(newSong);
                        }
                    }
                  semaphore.release();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
        }
    }
}

class Bar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Exchanger<String> exchanger = new Exchanger<>();
        Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(2);
        Phaser phaser = new Phaser(3);
        new Bard("Jack", "Hello world Java People", exchanger, phaser, semaphore);
        new Bard("Kim", "Hi students rock KPI", exchanger, phaser, semaphore);
        new Bard("Bill", "Ku over party fire",exchanger,phaser, semaphore);
        new Bard("Richard", "Winner star awesome things",exchanger,phaser, semaphore);
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас она приходит на метод - arriveAndAwaitAdvance() и там ждет чего то, вроде все работает и без него и тогда программа заканчивает свою работу

Answer (score 0):

В условии сказано обменяться словами нужно с каждым - поэтому Exchanger может быть не один - а у каждого барда (ну скажем как почтовый ящик голосовых сообщений чтобы легче было представить что происходит)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Exchanger;
import java.util.concurrent.Phaser;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class Bard2 implements Runnable {

    private List<String> song;
    private String name;
    private AtomicReference<Bard2> speaker;
    private Phaser phaser;
    private Exchanger<String> exchanger = new Exchanger<>();
    private List<String> newSong = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Bard2> bardList;


    public Bard2(List<String> song, String name, AtomicReference<Bard2> speaker, Phaser phaser, List<Bard2> bardList) {
        this.song = song;
        this.name = name;
        this.speaker = speaker;
        this.phaser = phaser;
        this.bardList = bardList;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            tellWordsToOthers();
            phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
            singTogether();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void tellWordsToOthers() throws Exception {
        int receiveCount = 0; //количество полученных слов
        int sendCount = 0;    //количество отправленных слов (одно и тоже слово считается 1 раз)
        while (sendCount < 2 || receiveCount < (bardList.size() - 1) * 2) {
            System.out.println("phase #" + phaser.getPhase());
            phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
            Bard2 oldSender = speaker.get();
            phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
            if (sendCount < 2 && oldSender != this) {
                speaker.set(this);
            }
            phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
            if (speaker.get() == this && sendCount < 2 ) {
                for (Bard2 bard : bardList) {
                    if (bard != this) {
                        System.out.println(name + " is sending to get...");
                        bard.exchanger.exchange(song.get(sendCount));
                    }
                }
                newSong.add(song.get(sendCount));
                sendCount++;
            } else {
                System.out.println(name + " is waiting to get...");
                String wordFromOther = exchanger.exchange(null);
                receiveCount++;

                newSong.add(wordFromOther);
            }
            System.out.println(name + " send: " + sendCount + " receive: " + receiveCount);
        }

    }

    private void singTogether() {
        System.out.println(name + " " + newSong);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AtomicReference<Bard2> speaker = new AtomicReference<>();
        Phaser phaser = new Phaser(4);
        Exchanger<String> exchanger = new Exchanger<>();

        List<Bard2> bards = new ArrayList<>();
        bards.add(new Bard2(Arrays.asList("Учил", "я", "Java", "между"), "Jack", speaker, phaser, bards));
        bards.add(new Bard2(Arrays.asList("делом", "а", "таже", "Python"), "Alice", speaker, phaser, bards));
        bards.add(new Bard2(Arrays.asList("и", "C#", "вот только", "лучше"), "Bob", speaker, phaser, bards));
        bards.add(new Bard2(Arrays.asList("надо", "было", "красивым", "девушкам", "писать"), "Antony", speaker, phaser, bards));

        bards.forEach(t -> new Thread(t).start());
    }
}
```